# How locate CHM filename in Processes?

Tags: .net, process, chm

I have a routine to search Windows Processes behind some files.

It functions normally but, when I try to locate a .CHM file (Compiled Help File), I cannot find it since its name in processes is not the filename, but the original HELP name. See below:

- Filename = **myhelp.chm**   <<< I search for this!
- HelpName = **Good Systems-Help File** << what I see in Windows
  Processes

So, neither my routine can locate the CHM in memory, nor I can locate this name within the CHM file. Do you have any idea about how deal with this?

Comment: What do you mean by `I have a routine to search Windows Processes ...`?

Comment: My application search for opened windows and files in the Windows Processes area. There I can locate if a file is (or not) open.

Answer (score 1):

The short story - very deep in the operating system and 20 years old (but good) HTMLHELP (CHM) technology. Heavy to find a quick solution but read to the end of my answer.

**Further information:**

You know, HH.EXE is distributed with HTMLHelp (HH) so you can rely on it being present. It lives in the Windows folder and has a limited number of command-line options. HH.EXE is associated with .CHM files. So double-click a *.CHM file and Windows will open the file using HH.EXE. Its a very small file, it mostly passes the help filename onto a HH API library. HH.EXE is not single instance, if you open a CHM file three times using HH.EXE, then three help windows will appear.

As mentioned above the executable for HTMLHelp is HH.EXE, which is basically a wrapper around Internet Explorer (the heart of HTML Help runtime is hhctrl.ocx and shdocvw.dll). You can see this by running `hh.exe myfile.html`, where myfile.html is some not compiled (!) HTML file.

```
start /B hh.exe D:\_working\HTMLHelp.chm
```

You may call a CHM by batch file like shown above, by double-click in Windows Explorer or by calling as application help - always the same result in Task Manager. The snaps show (you know) the opened CHM and the Task Manager. See the CHM's window title bar "Test file for HTML Help on 4K monitors" specified by the help author. Same thing you'll find in the process list of Task Manager.

[image]

[image]

The -800 or -title command-line options - when used - are ignored if you have specified any default window types in your compiled help file.

The next snap shows all is a Compiled Help Module (CHM) and you need special HH Utilities like [FAR HTML](http://www.help-info.de/en/FAR/far_html.htm) to go into. The text I mentioned above is compiled as `Window Caption` of the Main help window. Maybe interesting info but not the way to go.

[image]

This said, things depend on your environment. So, you have to decide using a tool like e.g. [`ProcessMonitor`](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx), filter `hh.exe` operation `ProcessStart` and extract the path to the CHM file from `Detail` like shown below. You'll find the **full path to CHM** there!

[image]

In PowerShell you can get the command line parameter of a process via WMI e.g. for all running help viewer `hh.exe` windows:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for so detail explanation, but my problem is HOW to locate that title when the user click on CHM. If searching all dictionary pairs of Windows Processes, I can see the filename there - but if the filename is different of the Title, I cannot really check if the file is opened. Note: teh file is opened within .NET code by user choice (he points to a file and .NET calls it using Process.Start().

Comment: @David I have answered it only indirectly, but the CHM file name is not compiled into the CHM file and the CHM window title is independent of the file name. For a proof: CHM files can be renamed and moved to another directory - there are no problems on a local Windows PC.
It is not quite clear for me why you want to search for open CHM files. Calling a help window from application by `Process.Start(helpFilePath);` is not the best way.  When the application is closed by user the Help window remains open and must be closed manually. Help.ShowHelp is better way to call CHM.

Comment: Thank you. My problem is not how to open the help file itself but detect opened files by users. The user can select ANY file and open it using my application, which monitors when the file is closed (a different Thread does it). Once closed, the file is encrypted. So, my problem is how to locate files that have TITLES (and similar) and when opened, Windows Process shows these titles instead the filename. Since I don't know them (like PDF and CHM), I get an error on them. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I added a Powershell info to my answer - maybe you can use PowerShell or add something like that into your application (C# or VB). e.g. (not tested) `If Process.GetProcessesByName("hh").Length > 0 Then encrypt / close else close endIf`.

Comment: Thank you very much!, but my problem is not detect HH in the Processes but the lack of the title within  :).  I can locate HH with its Title but without the filename - the only data I have to check if it is present in memory/running.  Anyway, thank you very much!